# Sitecore Powershell Reports/ListView: retrieving items from ID returned by the query

Tags: powershell, sitecore, sitecore8

A template named "User" has a field called "Location" which is the ID of another item; in Powershell I use **Show-ListView** to return a list of fields, but Location shows the raw ID, while I would much rather display the Name of the Location involved.

I attempted to retrieve this information, but I'm not sure about which syntax is available within the Powershell query. My attempt is as follows:

```
Get-Item master: -Query "/sitecore/content/sites/data/people//*[@@templatename='Person']" |
    Show-ListView -property "First Name",
    @{Label="Surname"; Expression={$_."Surname"}},
    @{Label="Location"; Expression={[Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem]::FromId($_."Location").Title}}
```

...which yields nothing.

```
$_."Location"
```

is the ID of an item; is there a way to retrieve its fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The secret lies in the fact that by default Sitecore do not have the convenient properties that are transformed from fields. In this case we're talking about the `Title` property on your location item. What you can do is:

1) Fetch the location Item through the provider like so:

```
Get-Item master: -Query "/sitecore/content/sites/data/people//*[@@templatename='Person']" |
    Show-ListView -property "First Name",
    @{Label="Surname"; Expression={$_."Surname"}},
    @{Label="Location"; Expression={(Get-Item master:\ -ID $_."Location").Title}}
```

notice the call to `Get-Item` in the last line.

2) if you need to fetch it through the Sitecore API for some reason, you can pipe it to `Initialize-Item` and we'll wrap those properties around the Item object for you like so:

```
Get-Item master: -Query "/sitecore/content/sites/data/people//*[@@templatename='Person']" |
    Show-ListView -property "First Name",
    @{Label="Surname"; Expression={$_."Surname"}},
    @{Label="Location"; Expression={([Sitecore.Configuration.Factory]::GetDatabase("master").GetItem($_."Location") | Initialize-Item).Title}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is enlightening.